# Continuous vector field tangent to even dimensional sphere which only vanish at one point

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, vector-fields, spheres

I am working on path motion planning on different topological spaces. In order to prove the existence of some motion planning algorithms I would like to use that given an even dimensional sphere, we can always find a continuous vector field tangent to it which only vanishes at one point.

**My attempts:**

First of all I think that that statement should be true since we could use the stereographic projection (which is a diffeomorphism) in order to "bring" or "take back" a smooth vector field defined on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (assuming we are dealing with $\mathbb{S}^{2n}$) which only vanishes at one point.

But I am doing a project about other topic and if I use that, then I should introduce and define charts, diffeomorphisms...etc and I am restricted on the number of pages. That is the reason why I am looking for other argument, moreover, I don't need smoothness so that would be like killing a mosquito with a cannon ball.

What about using that the stereographic projection is an homeomorphism and using the same idea as before? Continuity is preserved by homeomorphisms so I would have finished.  But again if could be possible I would like to avoid using stereographic projection.

**What I have consulted:**

[this question on stackexcange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71595/a-smooth-vector-field-on-s2-vanishing-at-a-single-point?rq=1)

[Marcel Berger, Bernard Gostiaux book on differential geometry where they draw a picture in the case of dimension 2](https://books.google.es/books?id=SFXSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA257&lpg=PA257&dq=vector%20field%20on%20even%20sphere%20which%20only%20vanishes%20in%20one%20point&source=bl&ots=aU19Qc8d98&sig=EWFxxt51qq0hJi7YKsfY_IdbSx8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ_aGPyJ3LAhUDuBoKHU_jBrAQ6AEIOjAE#v=onepage&q=vector%20field%20on%20even%20sphere%20which%20only%20vanishes%20in%20one%20point&f=false)

**My question:**

What other idea do you suggest? Is there an intuitive vector field that works and I am missing it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "vector field" I'm guessing you mean a field of _tangent_ vectors. $\qquad$

Comment: yes, you're absolutely right @MichaelHardy. I edited the title. Thanks sor pointing out that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be too hard to construct such a vector field. The hard trick is proving that all vectors fields on $S^{2n}$ vanish at some point.

Start with the tangent vectors to a rotation about some axis. This provides a vector field with exactly two $0$ points. Now morph the sphere below to bring these two points together. Everwhere off the joined point, the vector field has undergone a continuous transformation, so it remains a vector field. At the joined point, the behavior is singular, but since the vector field vanishes there, the singularity is smoothed out.

Comment: I already have proved that all continuous vectors fields on $\mathbb{S}^{2n}$ vanish at some point. I think I intuitively understand what you mean despite I don't get an analytic expression, which is what I want. I started by picturing such a vector field, for example:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5QLY6KP0JyvNjlxb256NThteUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Now by morphing I think in an homotopy or something like that but I think I won't work. Or at least I don't see how to write down some analytic expression.